A reading comprehension question about the best title
The article:Why it's hard to spot a liar
According to the article, our English teacher gave us a multiple choice question:

What is the best title of the text?
A. How we can spot a liar.
B. What a liar’s tricks are.
C. Why it’s hard to spot a liar.
D. Who are good at lying.

Of course the answer our teacher gave us is C. But I wonder why A isn’t the best answer. The author seems to focus on how to spot a liar by analyzing the reasons why it’s hard to spot a liar. What the author actually tries to show, I thought, is there are some ways to spot a liar, though it’s no easy task.

Are you just supposed to pick one of A, B, C or D (i.e. supply a single letter), or write something (a short essay) explaining your choice? If the latter, then the point is to get you to present an opinion (any opinion!) and convincingly (hopefully) argue for it.

Yes, there are two okay answers. You are missing the instruction in multiple-choice tests: Pick the best answer, not the correct one. C is better, so A no longer matters.

Could you tell me why C is better than A?

The article has very little about spotting a liar, that's why. Which paragraphs address that?

Suggestions are given in the fourth and fifth paragraphs . Also, the reasons are mainly in the third paragraph.
